# How to fix "[rospack] Error: package 'my_package' not found"

Tags: python, linux, ros

I am creating a new ros package inside the catkin_ws/src after creating any package I use the catkin_make command to build ros packages with new packages. But When I try to find my new package in the ros packages using **rospack find**  command or **rospacklist | grep [my_package]**, I can't find it and I see this error.

I am using Ros Melodic version on the Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

```
mehmet@ABRA-A5-V6-1:~/catkin_ws/src$ ls 

CMakeLists.txt  graduation_tutorial  tutorial

mehmet@ABRA-A5-V6-1:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
```

After this command.

```
mehmet@ABRA-A5-V6-1:~/catkin_ws/src$ rospack find tutorial

[rospack] Error: package 'tutorial' not found
```

I want to find and execute my own race packages. What Should I do for my Ros system?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I suspect you need to source your workspace. After you do a `catkin_make` (or `catkin build` if you're using the [catkin_tools](https://catkin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package) and it tells you it was successful, type in a terminal:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

That will set some environment variables and make your packages in that workspace recognizable to the rest of the system. You should then be able to do

```
rospack find tutorial
```

and it should print the path to that package. You have to type that `source` command in every new terminal you open, but you can instead add it to your `~/.bashrc` file so it is automatically sourced when you open a new terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I understood why this error happened. After I applied these commands, it worked. So, I added the source command in the ~/.bashrc file. Now, it works whenever I open a new terminal.

Comment: This does not work on my end. I ran exactly the same script as specified in the beginner tutorial, save for the name being `turtlesim_ex1` as required in my assignment. However, `rospack find beginner_tutorials` generates this same error after running that `source` command.